# Remove Django url namespace and serve app from root urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a Django app which I created as a reusable app with its own urls.py. The app's urls.py is included from the project's root urls.py:

```
url(r'^app/', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),
```

The full urls are example.com/app/view1, example.com/app/view2 . I want to remove the /app/ part from the urls so the views can be called by urls directly following the domain name such as exmpale.com/view1, example.com/view2. I refer to the urls in templates and views as 'app:urlname'.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Ideally without having to edit all of my templates.

Comment: Just change your url pattern to `url(r'^/', include('app.urls', namespace='app')),`

Comment: So simple! It's actually without the '/' - url(r'^', include('mtm.urls', namespace='mtm')).